# Is there AWS SCP to block users from creating elastic IP EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

Can an AWS organization account stop or block child AWS accounts from launching public AWS EC2 instances having elastic ip? Would like those users within those accounts to launch only private ec2(s).

Is there any other way if not SCP?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways. SCP via AWS Config is one, you can use the [ec2-instance-no-public-ip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/ec2-instance-no-public-ip.html) or [subnet-auto-assign-public-ip-disabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/subnet-auto-assign-public-ip-disabled.html) rules. And you also have option to control it via IAM by denying the [AllocateAddress](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_AllocateAddress.html) permission

Comment: Any example to use SCP via AWS Config?

Answer (score 1):

There is no SCP directly exists for this use case. But you can write one.

> Grants permission to allocate an Elastic IP address (EIP) to your account and various other operations related to the network interfaces with condition key below.

```json
ec2:AllocateAddress
ec2:AssociateAddress
ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
```

With condition key

```
ec2:AssociatePublicIpAddress
```

> Filters access by whether the user wants to associate a public IP address with the instance

[Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-ec2_AssociatePublicIpAddress)

You might wanna check this too in case you want to make things simpler

[Example: Prevent any VPC that doesn't already have internet access from getting it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps_examples.html#examples_vpc)